# fan off + system slowdown in battery mode

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, fan, temperature

If my laptop runs on the battery, its fan is off/silent and the system sometimes slows down till complete freeze. I believe it's somehow related with power management. For comparison, when I run an intensive application (e.g. Unigine_Heaven) with power cable plugged in, it runs at 20fps, temperature increases to 70°, fans are on/loud. When the cable is unplugged, its slows downto 5fps, temperature falls to 55° and the whole system becomes very slow: mouse, keyboard, all other applications etc. I would prefer the fans working normally and the system responsive disregards the battery saving. Is it possible to configure power management in Ubuntu 14.04?

Details: I do not intend playing games on the battery, Unigine_Heaven here is only an example to make CPU intensively working. I use hybrid graphics Intel+Nvidia with primusrun and for this test run Unigine_Heaven completely on CPU. Temperature is measured with psensor.